# Bigcommerce API - In Orders, what does the id represent?

Tags: bigcommerce

In orders(https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders), what does the id represent? Is that order_id? id is explained in documentation as "The ID of the order, a read-only value. Do not pass in PUT or POST."

However, if we look at id property under order product(https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/order_product), there are id, order_id, and product_id.

I am confused what id represent in orders and order product.

Answer (score 0):

Both values represent individual auto assigned unique numbers. When you upload or add new products each product is assigned a product_id and when an order is placed or in the abandon cart saver feature it gets assigned a order_id.

If you go to the Bigcommerce product page and view-source you will see your product_id

example `<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="94" />`

Hope that helps